# how to redirect links with response code 500 and 404 using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have some links with response code 500 and 404 in google webmaster for which google penalizes me. I have tried to add the following in htaccess file :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
Redirect 301 /home/action https://test.com/home/index
```

But these don't seem to work as I still get 404 not found error on page. Can anyone suggest why these links do not redirect.